# How would I go about debugging this SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, identifier

I have a large SQL query which is giving me some trouble. here is query :

```
-- Invoice-to
SELECT hzp.party_number customer_number
     , hzp.party_name   customer_name
     , hzp.party_type
     , hzp.address1
     , hzp.address2               
     , hzp.address3
     , hzp.address4
     , hzp.city
     , hzp.postal_code
     , hzp.state
     , hzp.country
     , hzp.status
     , hzps.party_site_number
     , hzac.account_number
     , hzac.account_name
     , site.site_use_code
     , rct.remit_to_address_id
FROM hz_parties hzp
LEFT OUTER JOIN hz_party_sites hzps ON hzps.party_id = hzp.party_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN hz_cust_accounts hzac ON hzac.party_id = hzp.party_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN hz_locations hzl ON hzl.location_id = hzps.location_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN hz_cust_acct_sites_all acct ON acct.party_site_id = hzps.party_site_id 
  /*LEFT OUTER                               */  --AND acct.cust_account_id = hzac.cust_account_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN hz_cust_site_uses_all site ON site.cust_acct_site_id = acct.cust_acct_site_id
                                          AND site.site_use_code = 'BILL_TO' /* site was hcsu? */
LEFT OUTER JOIN ra_customer_trx_all rct ON rct.remit_to_address_id = acct.remit_to_address_id
;
--checked , had an erro
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Error at Command Line:27 Column:70
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ACCT"."REMIT_TO_ADDRESS_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

I looked up invalid ID , but it's not helping me with the logic of it. Any tips appreciated

Comment: Does table hz_cust_acct_sites_all have a column named remit_to_address_id?  The error message suggests that it does not.

Comment: @DanBracuk - True, it does not have that column . Ah, OK let me see if I can figure this. thanks!!!